# Is ir.archive.ubuntu.com down?

Tags: apt, mirrors

When I try to use sudo apt update or install it gives me the following error:

```
Unable to connect to ir.archive.ubuntu.com
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Possibly by using another mirror; you're currently using one hosted by  https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/archive.ubuntu.petiak.ir-archive (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors)

Comment: @guiverc How can I find out which mirror ir.archive.ubuntu.com is using and how can I change it?

Comment: You might want to change your mirrors with the ones provided by `Asiatech` or `Shatel`. Check this out: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

Comment: I did a `ping -c 1 ir.archive.ubuntu.com` and from the result of that I could see it on the link I provided in brackets, ie. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors  (where I confirmed the output matched your country code - ie. IR to check what my conclusions)

Comment: It seems to be up again.

Answer (score 2):

Go and search in https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/

It will give you result is it down for you or everyone